# UniRx Scheduler with custom time scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, system.reactive, unirx

Is there a way to create a Scheduler that has additional time scale applied? Say a unit in a game is slowed down, I'd like it's Scheduler run slower so that all streams based on that Scheduler run slower as well.

Comment: It's possible with a virtual time scheduler, but I'm not sure if that's available in UniRx.

Comment: @Asti thanks, will ding on the topic and see if it can be done with UniRx